# Set behavior with setTimeout and clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a JQuery tooltip plugin but I have a problem.

I need to be able to move the mouse over the tooltip ...

I tried to make this work with setTimeout and clearTimeout but no luck.

I have a working version here: http://www.codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/KdyJH

The important code is at the end of Mouse Enter event and in Mouse Leave event.

Here is the plugin code:

```
// JQuery
(function ($) {

  // Tooltip
  $.fn.Tooltip = function (options) {

    var defaults = {          
      class: 'Tooltip',
      content: '',
      delay: [200, 200],
      cursor: false,
      offset: [0, 1],
      hide: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeOut(200);
      },
      show: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeIn(200);
      }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var identity = "Tooltip_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 2000 + 1) + 2000);

    var info = { ready: false, shown: false, timer: null, title: '' };

    $(this).each(function (e) {     

      var $this = $(this);
      info.title = $this.attr('title') || '';

      // Mouse enter           
      $this.mouseenter(function (e) {                  

        if (info.ready) {

          var $tooltip = $("#" + identity);

        } else {

          var $tooltip = $("<div>").attr("id", identity).attr("class", options.class).appendTo('body');

          $tooltip.html(options.content != '' ? (typeof options.content == 'string' ? options.content : options.content($this, $tooltip)) : this.title);

          info.ready = true;
          $this.attr('title', '');

        }

        if (options.cursor) {

          var position = [e.clientX + options.offset[0], e.clientY + options.offset[1]];

        } else {

          var coordinates = $this[0].getBoundingClientRect();

          var position = [

            (function () {

              if (options.offset[0] < 0)
                return coordinates.left - Math.abs(options.offset[0]) - $tooltip.outerWidth();
              else if (options.offset[0] === 0)
                return coordinates.left - (($tooltip.outerWidth() - $this.outerWidth()) / 2);
              else
                return coordinates.left + $this.outerWidth() + options.offset[0];

            })(),

            (function () {

              if (options.offset[1] < 0)
                return coordinates.top - Math.abs(options.offset[1]) - $tooltip.outerHeight();
              else if (options.offset[1] === 0)
                return coordinates.top - (($tooltip.outerHeight() - $this.outerHeight()) / 2);
              else
                return coordinates.top + $this.outerHeight() + options.offset[1];

            })()

          ];

        }

        $tooltip.css({ left: position[0] + 'px', top: position[1] + 'px' });


        // HERE THE TOOLTIP IS DISPLAYED
        timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
          options.show($this, $tooltip.stop(true, true));
        }, options.delay[0] || 0);


        // THIS IS THE EVEN WHEN THE MOUSE MOVES OVER THE TOOLTIP.
        // IT SHOULD CANCEL THE HIDE CALL OF THE TOOLTIP.
        // AFTER THE MOUSE MOVES AWAY FROM THE "A" TAG THERE SHOULD BE A DELAY.
        // THE DELAY WOULD ALLOW THE MOUSE TO MOVE TO THE TOOLTIP.
        // IN THAT CASE THE HIDE CALL SHOULD BE CANCELED.
        $("#" + identity).mouseenter(function() {
          window.clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = null;
        });

        // HERE THE TOOLTIP GETS HIDDEN WHEN THE MOUSE MOVES AWAY FROM IT
        $("#" + identity).mouseleave(function () {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
            options.hide($this, $tooltip);
          }, options.delay[1]);
        });

      }), // Mouse enter

      // HERE THE TOOLTIP GETS HIDDEN WHEN THE MOUSE MOVES AWAY FROM THE "A" TAG
      // WHEN THE MOUSE MOVES OVER THE TOOLTIP THIS SHOULD BE CANCELED.
      $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        options.hide($this, $("#" + identity).stop(true, true));
      }) // Mouse leave               

    }); // Each

  }; // Tooltip

})(jQuery); // JQuery
```

Remember that I have the working example in: 
http://www.codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/KdyJH

Comment: Please pin down the problem to a particular place in the code. As is, your question is essentially "please debug this for me not having all the relevant code", which is not constructive. Voting to close.

Comment: I did that in my text ... but I just added comments of what I am trying to do. Please, check the uppercase comments. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On link's `mouseleave` you have to set timeout for hiding the tooltip (so that it won't hide instantly and you'll have some time to hover it) and on tooltip's `mouseenter` you have to clear that timeout so it won't hide because of it (you already did the second part).
Check this :

http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/lagLb